# problems about error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.resolver.HostsFileParser.parseSilently()Ljava/util/Map;"

Tags: java, vert.x

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
public class app extends AbstractVerticle{
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception{
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
            routingContext.response()
            .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
            .end("hello vert.x");
        });
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8888);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new app());
    }
}
```

then error occurs as java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.resolver.HostsFileParser.parseSilently()Ljava/util/Map;

Comment: I would check the classpath as it seems your version of Netty is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
      routingContext.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("hello vert.x");
    });

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

run `mvn clean package` then `java -jar /path/to/jar`

Also in java `app` is not a valid class name.
Class names start with a capital e.g. `App`

Comment: Thank you about your answer. Actually I am just a freshman in this area. I use the software IntelliJ IDEA so I am not sure how to run mvn clean package and java -jar /path/to/jar as you recommended. Only change the name doesn't work actually. Also if I import io.vertx.example.util.Runner, which jar should I deploy??

Comment: @SunnieX sry for the Runner. removed that. its not needed. if you are using maven as your build tool, run `mvn clean package` in the terminal. then go to the /target directory and run the jar with `java -jar whatever-jar` that will deploy your verticle. I'd suggest looking up on youtube, if you're a freshman. there are lots of resources on this